# Can "experimental data from a quantum computer" be used to test separability probability conjectures?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, ibm-quantum-devices, experimental-realization

An article entitled "[Experimental data from a quantum computer verifies the generalize Pauli exclusion principle](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42005-019-0110-3)" by Scott E. Smart, David I. Schuster, and David A. Mazziotti has just appeared

In the study, they generate sets of random pure states of 3 fermions in 6 orbitals and examine their 1-RDM's (reduced density matrices). For this purpose, they employ "the IBM Quantum Experience devices (ibmqx4 and ibmqx2), available online, in particular, the 5-transmon quantum computing device". Can one adapt their approach to testing the "separability probability" question ([arXiv:quant-ph/9804024](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9804024)) in any form ([fermionic](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231041509), or otherwise)?

In particular, can the conjectures that the two-qubit separability probabilities are $\frac{8}{33}$, $\frac{25}{341}$ or 
$1-\frac{256}{27 \pi^2}$, depending upon the choice of Hilbert-Schmidt, Bures or operator monotone function $\sqrt{x}$ measures ([arXiv:1701.01973](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.01973), [arXiv:1901.09889](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.09889))  be evaluated? If one could generate random (using Fubini-Study measure) pure four-qubit states, and find the reduced two-qubit systems, then perhaps one could examine the Hilbert-Schmidt instance ([p. 422 of Bengtsson-Zyczkowski monograph](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometry-of-quantum-states/46B62FE3F9DA6E0B4EDDAE653F61ED8C)).

I see that there is 2011 and subsequent work of J. A. Miszczak ([arXiv:1102.4598](https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.4598)) concerning the (Mathematica) generation of random numbers through quantum processes, and their use in the production of random quantum states (such as I am seeking)--through standard (Ginibre-ensemble/random matrix theory) algorithms. But, I think, this is (presently?) comparatively slow in relation to pseudo-random means. Also, can the random states be generated "more directly" with the IBM devices? (Smart, Schuster, Mazziotti prepare initial pure states and then perform "arbitrary unitary transformations" ["generated on the quantum computer"] to obtain random pure states.)